# c++ pointer segfaults without compiler warning, works when previously assigned

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a difficulties understanding pointers and how/when they fail. So I made a tiny program which creates a pointer, assigns a value to it and then prints that value. Compiles fine with both gcc and clang and does not give any warnings when using the -Wall switch. Why does it segfault and why does it not segfault when I assign a different value to the pointer first? I thought I had initialized the pointer to somewhere. When I just declare the pointer without initialization, then I rightfully get a compiler warning. However, here I do not get a compiler warning, but it still segfaults.

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
  int *b = (int*)  12;  //pointer gets initialized, so it points to somewhere
  //int a = 13;   //works fine when uncommenting this and the next line
  //b = &a;
  *b = 11;
  std::cout << "*b = " << *b << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not good since you don't know where does the pointer `0xC` point to. Are you running on an embedded system with known address to use? I think what you want is `int *b = new int();`

Comment: Do I need to know where it points to? I just need it to point to some location that can hold an int, which I thought I did by initializing it. I usually do not care where `a` points to either, just have the os take care of it. The compiler also seems to think that this is fine. No, this is running on my desktop (linux), just for learning and understanding.

Comment: Do not use C-style casts as in `(int*)`. They can cast almost anything to anything else, whether it makes sense or not. If you use them the compiler often won't put out warnings, because it assumes you know what you are doing if you cast explicitly. Had you used the C++-style cast `static_cast<int*>(12)` or no cast at all, it would have complained. You are not allowed to use random addresses to access values. You may only use addresses of allocated memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pointer is a variable that save a memory address.
You "can" have any memory address in your pointer, but trying to read from memory space outside of where your application are allowed to read, will trigger the OS to kill you application with a segfault error.

If you allow me the metaphor:

> You can write on a paper the address of any person in your country. But if you try to enter that house without permission, you most probably will get stopped by the police.

Back to code:

```
int *b = (int*) 123; // ok, you can save what you want.
std::cout << *b << std::endl; // SEGFAULT: you are not allowed to read at 123.
```

When you uncomment the two lines of code:

```
int a = 13;
b = &a;
```

Basically, `b` is not any-more pointing to that forbidden `123` address, but to the address of `a`. `a` is in your own code, and it memory is not forbidden to you, so accessing `*b` after this is allowed.

Reading at any hard-coded address is not forbidden by C++ (in fact it is useful in some situations), but your OS may not allow you to mess with that memory.

On the other hand, the compiler is able to detect a variable being used without initialization, and can warn this case. This has nothing to do with raw pointers.

Comment: "_with the memory of others._": Address spaces are distinct between processes on modern desktop systems. It is just a matter of the virtual address not being mapped to any physical one for the process.

Comment: Right! I did not wanted to enter the topic of virtual memory, but I agree, it can be misleading. I fixed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is a variable to store an address.

```cpp
int *b = (int*)  12;
```

This declares `b` as a pointer to a value of type `int`, and initializes it with the address `12`. Do you know what resides at address `12`? No, you don't. Thus, you should not use that address.

```cpp
*b = 11;
```

This stores an integer `11` at the address pointed to by the pointer `b`. However, since pointer `b` points at address `12`, the integer `11` overwrites something at that address (we don't even know what does it overwrite, because we don't know what is there to begin with). This could corrupt heap or stack or program's code or just cause an access violation, anything can happen.

But if you first do this:

```cpp
b = &a;
```

Then pointer `b` now points at the address at which the variable `a` is stored. Thus, subsequently writing `11` at that address will just overwrite `a`'s value (from 13 to 11), a perfectly valid operation, no problems.

> I just need it to point to some location that can hold an `int`

Indeed, but this is not enough. Not only shall the location be able to hold an `int`, that location must also be available for your program to store such an `int`. This means the location needs to be either that of an existing object (e.g., of an existing variable of type `int`) or a newly allocated memory chunk capable of holding an `int`. For example:

```cpp
b = new int;
```

This will dynamically allocate the memory needed to store an `int`, and assign the address of the newly allocated memory to the pointer `b`.

Remember that after you're done with such dynamically allocated memory, you should deallocate it:

```cpp
delete b;
```

Otherwise, there will be a memory leak (at least until the whole process exits anyway).

Nowadays, in modern C++, there is rarely a need to use raw pointers to manage dynamic memory allocations/deallocations manually. You'd use standard containers and/or smart pointers for that purpose instead.

Comment: Ah, properly allocating memory works. Thanks, I will keep that in mind. Yeah, I am practicing for some embedded system where not everything is available, thus raw pointers.